# How to bring excel VBA UI to front

Tags: vba, excel

**My Codes**

I have the following codes whereby it opens a file browser when click a button on UI

```
Sub GetOpenFile()
    Dim fileStr As String

    On Error GoTo Error

    fileStr = Application.GetOpenFilename()
    If fileStr = "False" Then Exit Sub
    Workbooks.Open fileStr

    Exit Sub

    Error:
    MsgBox "Something went wrong or the file type/extension is wrong", vbExclamation, "Error"

    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

**My Problem**

After selected the file it is able to open the file. But the problem is, UI window goes to background whereby the newly opened file came to front. User always needs to either minimize or look for the UI in order to proceed with other activities.

**What I need**

Is there any way that UI will stay in front even after opened the file?

Comment: Note: You should define `Dim fileStr As Variant` because `GetOpenFilename` can return either a `Boolean` or a `String`. If you test like `fileStr = "False"` this will fail on any non-English Excel (eg on a German Excel you would need to test for `fileStr = "Falsch"` so your code is incompatible). But if you use `Variant` you can test for `fileStr = False` (note that here are no quotes!) which works on every localization because you test for a `Boolean` instead of a `String`.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Thank you for the comments. Definitely will change that. I wonder why I used quotes for False! Such a stupid mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am able to solve it by doing the following way. After opened the file, I stored the opened file name in a variable as below

```
mainFileName = ActiveWorkbook.Name
```

After that just minimized the window by using following codes

```
Windows(mainFileName).WindowState = xlMinimized
```